# Android Studio 2020.3.1, Can't Export Project to Zip file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm trying to use ***Android Studio 2020.3.1*** to export my project to a zip file, but it's not working.  I'm using *File->Export->Export To Zip*.   No matter which folder or drive I try to save it to, I can't see it.

I'm on Windows 10.  Btw, I just updated to **Artic Fox**.  **I was at 4.2.1** and it was failing then, and is still failing after the Artic Fox update.  Is anyone else having his problem?   Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

A few day ago, i faced same problem on my android studio setup. i found solution for that issues but not exact. you can follow this manners: First i did unintstall android studio and clear the cache, and install again then after Update the classpath, gradle buildToolsVersion, plugin...

it's Working for me